# How to test (Unit testing) reducer in React which filtered an array of objects

Tags: reactjs, testing, jestjs

I have a problem can't write a correct test for one of my reducers.

My reducer look:

```
export const initialState = {
  time: undefined,
  products: undefined,
  filteredProducts: [],
  search: ""
};

case "FILTER_BY_VALUE": {
      return {
        ...state,
        search: payload,
        filteredProducts: [
          ...state.products.filter(product =>
            product.name.toLowerCase().startsWith(payload.toLowerCase())
          )
        ]
      };
    }
```

My reducer filter an array of objects by value (in my example it is payload)

My test look :

```
it("FILTER_BY_VALUE", () => {
    const action = {
      type: "FILTER_BY_VALUE",
      payload: "dsf"
    };
    expect(data(initialState, action)).toEqual({
      ...initialState,
      search: action.payload
      //   filteredProducts: Object
    });
  });
```

Error is in image:
[image]

Comment: Can you share the full reducer and full data code? The initial guess is that `products` is `undefined` in your `initialState`

Comment: @skovy Can you see one more time? I updated post ( add initial state in reducer)

Comment: Based on the snippet you've provided `state.products` is still `undefined`. Without context it's difficult to provide help; we do not know what is contained in your state at the time the reducer runs.

Comment: @DaveNewton I fix my error, thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure that `initialState` passed in the `data` has a `products` field.

`products` seems to be an array from how it's used and contains objects having a `name` field.

```
it("FILTER_BY_VALUE", () => {
    const initialState = {
       products: [{name: 'dsffoo'}, {name: 'bardsf'}]
    }

    const action = {
      type: "FILTER_BY_VALUE",
      payload: "dsf"
    };

    expect(data(initialState, action)).toEqual({
      ...initialState,
      search: action.payload,
      filteredProducts: ['dsffoo']
    });
});
```

Comment: Can you see one more time? I updated post ( add initial state in reducer)